# Compiled assembly generates segmentation fault under Ubuntu

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I have the following code in assembly:

```
.section .text
  .global _start

_start:
  pushl %ebp
  movl  %esp, %ebp
  subl  $16, %esp
  movl  $4, -4(%ebp)
  movl  $6, -8(%ebp)
  mov   $0, %eax
  leave
  ret
```

which would in theory be the same as the following C code:

```
int(main) {
  int a = 4;
  int b = 6;
  return 0;
}
```

However, I get a Segmentation Fault when running the compiled and linked Assembly code using:

```
as -32 main.asm -o main.o
ld -melf_i386 -o main main.o
```

also, if I convert the C object file to assembly using `objdump` and use that code instead (which looks exactly the same). It all ends up an a Segmentation Fault.

Am I missing something or could the reason lie in the fact that I try to run 32bit assembly an a 64bit virtual Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I guess you should use system call instead of `ret` to exit. (I post this as comment because I'm not sure)

Comment: A C object file doesn't usually define a symbol `_start`. At best, it defines `main`, and then there's some secret glue code that calls `main` (crt1n.o etc).

Comment: You are not using the _C_ runtime and introducing your own code at the label `_start`. In this environment there is no return address on the stack to return to. You'll need to to use `int 0x80` and the exit [syscall](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) to end your program.

Comment: `int(main)`? What?

Comment: Even easier is to change `_start` to `main` and use _GCC_ to do the linking (_GCC_ acts as a wrapper around _LD_ but provides all the parameters to _LD_ to properly link in the _C_ runtime). After using _AS_ to assemble ( you can use _GCC_ to link with `gcc -m32 -o main main.o`). If you rename `main.asm` to `main.s` you can get _GCC_ to call _AS_ for you, and do the assembling and linking in one command `gcc -m32 -o main main.s`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far. But I think that there might be a misunderstanding in the question. I try to run the code using the above command. The assembly code from objdump was just a reference to check whether I wrote everything right (syntax of mov e.g).

Comment: Objdump of your code with `_start` doesn't have a main function, and that is a significant difference. I think you misunderstand the nature of what is going on. If you actually look at all the code in your _C_ version and your assembler version you'll find the entire _C_ runtime code is missing. That code makes the difference. Your assembler code and your _C_ code may look similar, but without the _C_ runtime in place the environment they are in is quite different.

Comment: Your assembler code is segfaulting on the `ret` because there is no _C_ runtime to go back to. Which takes me back to the first suggestion - use a `syscall` to exit, and remove the `ret`. That solves the problem. This has been thoroughly discussed in a multitude of ways on SO and there are blogs on the internet that discuss all this. If you were to spend some time doing searches you'd probably find the answers you are looking for.

Comment: If you used a debugger (like _GDB_) to step through your assembly code you should observe that the segfault is on the `ret`. Using a debugger to narrow down the failure point would have probably given you a better idea of what might be happening. A debugger is a very useful skill to have.

Comment: @hGen: `_start` isn't called by anything, it's not a function.  It's the entry-point for your executable.  When the OS starts running your code, `[esp]` points to `argc`, NOT to a valid return address, so you can't `ret`.  (This is another explanation of what Michael Petch already told you).  Check [the ABI docs](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) if you want to know more about the state of registers and memory at the start of `_main`.